# Display specific data from firebase inside Recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a tab layout inside one of my activity. Different tabs extends different fragments. I have to display data in **cardView inside fragment**.
CardView will contain all  data of a single child inside **Bills**.

This is the my activity

[image]

This is how my database look like:
[image]

Now the problem is instead of displaying data of  all child inside **Bills** node I need to filter them with two things **1. userId** and **2. billType**. Now if **userId** is matched with **mUser.getUid()** which is unique key of current user then it should check for **billType** suppose, if billType is Electronics then it should be visible inside electronics tab.

This is code of my fragment view of viewElectronics.java

```
public class viewElectronics extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mReceipt;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private DatabaseReference mRef;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.electronics_layout, container, false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bills");
    mReceipt = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.electronicsRecycler);
    mReceipt.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ReceiptViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ReceiptViewHolder>
            (DataModel.class, R.layout.reciept_row, ReceiptViewHolder.class, mRef){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ReceiptViewHolder viewHolder, DataModel model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setBillNo("Bill No : " + model.getBillNo());
            viewHolder.setStoreName("Store Name : " + model.getCompany());
            viewHolder.setDate("Date : " + model.getDate());
            viewHolder.setTime("Time : " + model.getTime());
            viewHolder.setBillTotal("Total : " + model.getTotal());
        }
    };

    mReceipt.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    return rootView;

}

}
```

Suppose only last node is having **billType: Electronics** then, Electronics Tab should contain last card. What changes do I need in this code.
Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you don't mind using the REST api to populate your rv, then you can use query with "filtering by key". https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

Answer (score 1):

you need to filter your bills node that can be easily done with .equalto

In your firebase recycler view at the database reference:

```
if( userid.equalto(mUser.getUid())){
mRef.orderbychild("billtype").equalto("Electronics")//whatever Category of fragment
else{(adapter.getposition(position).getKey()).orderbychild("billType")}
```

instead of using mRef as your database reference you can filter by saying to whichever category you need to display(NOTE:this applies only if youre duplicating your code in every fragment)

```
 mRef.orderbychild("billtype").equalto("Electronics")
```

Now, on the other hand when the userid doesnt match then display according to the bill type.